# Simply Scheme Exercises. Chapter 06 True and False

Tags: lisp, scheme

Greets, I'm new to SO so please take care of me.

Exercise [6.1](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~bh/ssch6/true.html) in [Simply Scheme](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~bh/ss-toc2.html) has the expression:

```
(cond (empty? 3)
      (square 7)
      (else 9))
```

My mind says it should evaluate (square 7) and return that. (empty? 3) is evaluated instead (returned the atom — tried it with other atoms and lists, same deal).

I'm confused.

What I know:

1. Everything in Scheme that is not false is true. If 3 is true and is not empty (#f), why does the cond expression return (empty? 3)?
2. The first argument to a cond expression is evaluated and where it is true, returns #t, the value defined or #undefined dependent on context. If false, it continues evaluating the cond arguments successively until it does so (or finds no suitable return value) then exits the cond.

What I don't know:

1. (empty? 3) on its own returns #f. Why does the cond terminate here and not evaluate (square 7)?
2. Why does the evaluation of (empty? 3) within the cond return the atom, not #t or #f?

I am using SCM with Slib and the additional libraries supplied with Simply Scheme (simply.scm,  functions.scm,  ttt.scm,  match.scm,  database.scm) loaded.

The empty? definition in simply.scm is beyond my scheme grasp at this point.

Comment: Could you still post the definition of `empty?`? These libraries are quite hard to find.

Comment: @[larsmans](http://stackoverflow.com/users/166749/larsmans) Sure. The function definition in [simply](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~bh/downloads/simply/simply.scm). The entire [library](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~bh/downloads/simply/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cond` form is like this:

```
(cond (something-to-check-for-truthiness value-if-truthiness-succeed)
        ...other checks in the same format as above  )
```

Now if you put your code into this format then.
`empty?` i.e just the function empty (not its call) fits in place of `something-to-check-for-truthiness` and a function is always a truth value hence number `3` is returned which is after `empty?` and fits into `value-if-truthiness-succeed` slot. So, there is no call to `empty?`function at all.

Comment: @[ankur](http://stackoverflow.com/users/553209/ankur) I read your explanation and got it immediately. After weeks of trudging through into Chapter 15 with a collection of hideous nested if expressions. Why isn't the book like this?

Comment: If you have compared this with other `cond` examples you probably had it, as you practice more your brain's s-expression parsing ability will increase and then the world will be at ur feet :)

Comment: You're probably right haha, the double parentheses got me as time wore on. Now clear as day, thanks in no small part, to you. As an aside, I've 3 rep. Can I +1? How?

Answer (score 1):

That's not quite what cond does.
cond accepts one or more arguments, each argument which must be a list of scheme-expressions.

(cond (#t)) is a valid cond statement.

It evaluates the first expression, and if true, evaluates as many additional s-epressions in that list, and returns the value of the last expression evaluated.

(cond (#t 1 2 3 4 (if (number? 0) "Yeah, sanity!" "It rubs lotion on it's skin"))) is a valid cond statement

Comment: Ha ha, confirmed with this `((lambda (test) (cond (test 1 2 3 4 "Yeah, sanity!" "It rubs lotion on it's skin")(else (exit)))) #f)` you're so right. Thought there was a limit in each cond argument to two expressions. Strange behaivour. Is there anywhere this is useful? I mean, the `1 2 3 4` in your example are evaluated but don't affect the cond return. Seems like a waste, especially if it were cpu intensive procedures in their place.

Comment: @usernvk Yes, in a pure function it's really only useful to have one or two expression, but it is usefull if each of the middle expressions produces a side effect, say writing to a file, printing the screen, or calling some sort of set! procedure.